# SharePoint List: How to use indexOf(@currentField, 'target') when field type is 'Hyperlink or Picture'

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

In a SharePoint List, I have a field of type 'Hyperlink or Picture' that has a URL like `'https://www.msn.com'`.

If the field is type text, I can do things like:

```
indexOf(@currentField, 'msn.com') > 0
```

If the field is type 'Hyperlink or Picture', this does not work.

What am I missing?

Update:
In the list view, it looks correct (note the correct icons):
[image]

When I add it to a page, the icons are not correct BUT the text is:
[image]

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to check based on "link" in hyperlink column or based on "description/display" text of hyperlink column?

Comment: The indexOf( ) function only indicates that an element does not exist if it returns -1. You should judge it to be greater than or equal to 0, because it's likely that you're going to find the element in position 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this on our SharePoint online site with hyperlink column in list. Here are the results:

JSON used:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(indexOf([$Hyperlink], 'msn.com') > -1, 'Found MSN', 'Not found')"
}
```

Where `Hyperlink` is the internal name of your SharePoint list column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

So, you should be able to check for any substring in "link" in hyperlink column using expression like:

```
indexOf([$Hyperlink], 'msn.com') > -1
```

If you want to check for any substring in "description/display" text of hyperlink column, use JSON like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(indexOf([$Hyperlink.desc], 'MSN') > -1, 'Found MSN', 'Not found')"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: `indexOf` operator is case-sensitive

Comment: after more research, it appears correct in the List view, but not when the list is added to a page.  I have updated the question to show the content.

Comment: Note how txtContent is updating, but the src is not working.

Comment: Can you change your src property using expression similar to txtContent (searching the index of `seismic` instead of `sharepoint`? Something like this: `=if(indexOf(@currentField, 'seismic') > -1, '<seismic.ico url>', '<microsoftSharePoint.png url>')`

Answer (score 0):

found a small typo in the logic, I believe this issue is closed.